# Float h4 right after image?

Tags: css

I am having problems with floating h4 after an image. It works as long as there is room in the table cell but as soon as you start to resize the window the text is floating left but UNDER the imag, I want ti to be right after even when the window is being resized.

Here is my code:

```
<td>
            <img src="theme/stats.png">
            <h4>We grow your channel!</h3>
            <div style="clear:both"></div>
            <br />
            We are the only network that guarantees to grow your channel from day ONE, even for small channels!
            Our network will <b>help you get a minimum of 5 new subscribers per day as soon as you join us!</b>
</td>

h4 {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: 'Bitter', serif;
    color: black;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
td img {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

You can see it live here, try to resize the window to see what happens with the title + icons: http://vizz.tv/

Comment: you're opening a `<h4>`but closing a `</h3>` (no good)

Comment: This isnt how float works, unless you specify fixed widths for the float, related content and the parent - when the space becomes too small, the elements will naturally float beneath one another

Comment: You will have to add a min-width to the table otherwise it will always push the title down when the table gets too small to have the image and title on the same line, ps unless this is an email template - tables should only be used for tabular data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should remove `float` property from `<h4>` to achieve this:

```
h4 {
    /* float: left; */
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 55px;
    ...
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FvjrZ/)

Comment: I am using yoru code that it does what I want. Is it possible to fix so that the second title row floats all the way under the image, as you can see on this image, there is a huge blank space under the image: http://i.gyazo.com/190d233631ac67bf9a35d36a2d55e992.png